# How to make some config file to my program?

Tags: ios, configuration

How to make some config file to my program so program can load settings from it befoce starting?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? How can a program load settings before it runs? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you are interested in is some kind of user preferences, yes?

use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class for application configuration. To establish the initial set of values before user customization make a plist file with the appropriate keys and values corresponding to what you wish to use in your application.

example of registering your default settings file with the system:

```
// Load default defaults.
// Defaults need to be registered prior to interface loading.
NSString* defaultsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"defaults" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary* defaultDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:defaultsPath];
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults registerDefaults:defaultDict];
```

then in your application logic you can simply ask the NSUserDefaults object for a value (any of the [plist supported types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html)) for a given key using the various methods of `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL myBool = [defaults boolForKey:@"myBool"];
// you can also get strings, data, numbers, dates, arrays, and dictionaries
```